# Is the permutation matrix $P$ that interchanges only two rows (or columns) symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the permutation matrix $P$ that interchanges only two rows (or columns) symmetric? Is the product of two such permutations necessarily symmetric? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. As to "why?", the ugly approach is to write its elements. LEt your matrix be $P$ with the elements $p_{ij}$ and let it exchange elements $k,l$ ($k \ne l$). Then

$$p_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1, & i = j \not\in \{k,l\}, \\
1, & i = k,\ j = l, \\
1, & i = l,\ j = k, \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

However, there is a nicer approach. We know that permutations are orthogonal, so $P^T P = I$, i.e., $P^T = P^{-1}$. However, if you swap two (same) elements twice and don't touch the others, you get what you started with, so $P^2 = I$, i.e., $P^{-1} = P$. So,

$$P^T = P^{-1} = P.$$

The product is symmetric if and only if the two permutations swap distinct elements, i.e., if and only if $P_1$ swaps $k_1,l_1$ and $P_2$ swaps $k_2,l_2$ such that $\{k_1,l_1\} \cap \{k_2,l_2\} = \emptyset$. Try proving it yourself.